# stl map with different value types?

Tags: templates, dictionary, stl

I want to store References to different Objects in a map, but I don't know how to define the map.

e.g:

```
map<string, & ObjectReferenceOfAnyKind> myList;

myList[ "keyA",  stringA );
myList[ "keyBlist",  vector );
myList[ "file",   fileObject );

string &value = (string&) myList["keyA"]; 
CFile &fobj = (CFile&) myList["file"];
```

Any suggestion how to solve this?

Comment: [http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/any.html](boost::any)?

Answer (score 1):

STL maps (like all STL containers) only store values belonging to a single type. So, you could use pointers to a base class or a union as the value type. Boost offers a modern discriminating union with [Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/variant.html).